# Are there any hosting solutions for a reverse proxy?

Tags: web-hosting, proxy

I'm looking for a reverse proxy to get around the Great Firewall of China. Is there a service where I can point my DNS to their servers, and choose a site to proxy from?

If not, what is the cheapest solution for a low traffic site? I thought about using Apache on EC2, but it seems a little complicated, and it would cost about $40.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would buy a really cheap VPS, lowendbox.com has offers listed from a few quid a month. Then install something like ziproxy. I have set this up in Ubuntu and it was really easy, installed then changed settings in my browser. all traffic was then going via my server.

Comment: I think you're thinking of a forward proxy, but I did something similar to what you suggest.  Looking at ziproxy lead me to nginx, which was easy to configure as a reverse proxy.  I did choose Ubuntu as the OS because installation was easy.  Thanks for the link to lowendbox, that's perfect for hosting.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has a free tier that you can use which would let you u do just that.
http://aws.amazon.com/free/

Comment: Technically they do, but I signed up before they started that, and it's only good for a year.

Comment: Plus it's only free while you stayed with the transfer limits. If your work involves uploading or downloading lots of data, you can quickly see costs escalate.